# Memory leak in AudioServicesPlaySystemSound using ARC

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I would need some help solving this memory leak problem. I am using ARC.

The potential leak is on this line:

```
NSURL *aFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
```

Here is the code:

```
// === Check if the game should play sound === //
if (sound == YES) {
    //==== PLAY THE LOOSING SOUND ====//
    // Form a URL to the sound file, which in init using the Path
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *filePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"wrong2" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *aFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];

    // Create a sound ID, 
    SystemSoundID myID;
    // Register the sound
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)aFileURL, &myID) ;
    // Play the sound!
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(myID);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace `__bridge_retained` by `__bridge`.

`__bridge_retained` would mean that you transfer the ownership of `aFileURL` to `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID()` and that function would have to release it (which it doesn't).

And I think you should also call

```
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(myID)
```

when the sound object is no longer needed.

**Tip:** When the static analyzer shows the "Potential leak" warning, click on the blue icon to the left of the warning and you will see detailed information about the problem.